# Python Bokeh - interactive legend hiding glyphs - not working

Tags: python, bokeh, legend, interactive

I try to implement Bokeh interactive legend, to filter the data plotted based on user selection. I need some help to figure out what is wrong with my code; I get the some glyphs for each use, different color (see the images bellow).

```
#Import libraries
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Category20_20
import pandas as pd

output_notebook()
#Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index': ['9', '10', '11', '12', '13'],
        'Size': ['25', '15', '28', '43', '18'], 
        'X': ['751', '673', '542', '362', '224'],
        'Y': ['758', '616', '287', '303', '297'],
        'User': ['u1', 'u1', 'u2', 'u2', 'u2'],
        'Location': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D'], 
        })

# Create plot

p = figure(plot_width=450, plot_height=450)
p.title.text = 'Title....'

users=list(set(df['User']))
size=df['Size']
for data, name, color in zip(df, users, Category20_20):
    p.circle(x=df['X'], y=df['Y'], size=size, color=color, alpha=0.8, legend=name)

p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy="hide"

show(p)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this loop

```py
for data, name, color in zip(df, users, Category20_20):
    p.circle(x=df['X'], y=df['Y'], size=size, color=color, alpha=0.8, legend=name)
```

you're:

- Iterating over column names of the data frame (because Pandas is very confusing in this regard), so your number of points will be limited (because `zip` stops at the shortest collection)
- Not using `data`
- Passing *full* data to `p.circle`, meaning you have two sets of circles that have completely identical coordinates and sizes
- Using the `legend` keyword, which is deprecated

Instead, try this:

```py
users=list(set(df['User']))
for name, color in zip(users, Category20_20):
    user_df = df[df['User'] == name]
    p.circle(x=user_df['X'], y=user_df['Y'], size=user_df['Size'],
             color=color, alpha=0.8, legend_label=name)
```

Comment: Thank you, Eugene! It's working now. I have an issue with legend_label, getting an error..."AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'legend_label' to Circle,....".  No error when I use legend instead of legend_label.

Comment: Ah, you're using an outdated version of Bokeh. If you want, you can upgrade it and use `legend_label`. If not, just continue using `legend`.